# select in a drop-down menu is not dropping down

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, jinja2, html-select

Why don't my dropdown-menus drop down?
I am unfamiliar with using style sheets and wonder if I have to tell it something because in earlier appengine work without css, the menus dropped down as expected.

[image: Dropdowns that don't drop down.]

**Could the problem be that the jinja2 syntax is different from the django syntax upon which this template is based?** I cannot find any jinja2 docs for this situation.

```
#inputdata {margin:0 20%}
#inputdata {background:#bfe2f9}


<div id="inputdata">
    <label>Year:</label>
      <select name="year">
        {% for year in years %}
        <option 
    {% ifequal year yearset %}
    selected="selected"
    {% endifequal %}
        value={{year}}>{{year}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    <label>Month:</label>
      <select name="month">
        {% for month in months %}
        <option 
    {% ifequal month monthset %}
    selected="selected"
    {% endifequal %}
        value={{month}}>{{month}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    <label>Day:</label>
      <select name="day">
        {% for day in days %}
        <option 
    {% ifequal day dayset %}
    selected="selected"
    {% endifequal %}
        value={{day}}>{{day}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML markup look like?

Comment: can we see your css too please

Comment: @stevether Like this: `<select><option value="All the years!">[2012, 2013, 2014]</option></select>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are passing `years`, `months` and `days` as lists that are too deeply nested.  If `len(years) == 1` then you'll want to change what you are passing to Jinja from this:

```
years = [[2012, 2013, 2014]]
```

to this:

```
years = [2012, 2013, 2014]
```

(And do the same for `months` and `days`).

Also, Jinja2 doesn't have an `ifequals` tag - you can just use the `if` block:

```
{% for year in years %}
<option {% if year == yearmark %}selected="selected"{% endif %} value="{{year}}">
{{ year }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Brilliant. You fixed all 3 problems in my code. len(years) == 1, yearmark instead of yearset, and {%if instead of (%ifequal . Thanks very much.

Comment: Wait...it turns out that jinja2 appears to accept both yearmark and yearset and both {%ifequal and {%if. So the only real problem was my new code which created years = [[2012, 2013, 2014]] instead of years = [2012, 2013, 2014]. Thanks, again.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to look like

```
<select>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>
```

http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlselect.php/

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <select><option value="All the years!">[2012,2013,2014]</option></select>
> ```

That isn't how `<select>` tags work. You only have *one option* so there is nothing to drop down.

You need to break your selectable items into their own option tags:

```
<select>
  <option>2012</option>
  <option>2013</option>
  <option>2014</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Ha, ha! I have no idea what OP's markup looks like, I was just being facetious.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your syntax is something like:

```
<select>
  <option>[2012, 2013, 2014]</option>
</select>
```

When it should look like:

```
<select>
  <option value="2012">2012</option>
  <option value="2013">2013</option>
  <option value="2014">2014</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, I had tried this syntax, also, but got the same result:  value="{{year}}">{{year}}</option>